# how to display 2 array list in one mat table datasource in angular?

Tags: angular

JSON:(Here I have nested array like this. array1 has number of objects and array2 has number of objects. For example array1 => 2materials, array2 => 2 materials, array3 => 1 material ,totally,I need to show 5 materials in one datasource table. Can you help me?  )

```
   const result = [{
                        test:[{
                            array1:[{
                                          id:1,
                                          qty: 12,
                                          material:{
                                                    id:1,
                                                    title:"Cookies"
                                                   }
                                        },
                                         {
                                             id:2,
                                             qty: 10,
                                          material:{
                                                    id:2,
                                                    title:"biscuit"
                                                   }
                                         }]
                               },
                               {
                            array2:[{
                                          id:1,
                                          qty: 12,
                                          material:{
                                                    id:1,
                                                    title:"Cookies1"
                                                   }
                                        },
                                         {
                                             id:2,
                                             qty: 10,
                                          material:{
                                                    id:2,
                                                    title:"biscuit1"
                                                   }
                                         }]
                               },
                                ]
                       array3:[{
                                      id:1,
                                     material:{
                                               id:1,
                                               title: "material1"
                                            }
                                    },
                                   {
                                    id:2,
                                     material:{
                                               id:2,
                                               title: "material2"
                                            }
                                    }]
                     }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate your two arrays to get one single array to display.

```
const testArr1 = result['test']['array1'];
const testArr2 = result['test']['array2'];
const arr3 = result['array2'];

const arraysConcatenated = testArr1 .concat(testArr2 , arr3);
```